# How to remove 500 error. Having removed the 404 error earlier?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Well i have been trying to implement infinite scroll on some posts of my wordpress website.
And it does work well on my test server. Rendering me no error at all.

But well when i uploaded on the main server( same settings as the test server) i got a 404 file not found error even though the file was there.

now here is the script. that has an ajax call at the end. via url:"infi.php"
content of infi.php

```
<?php 
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', FALSE);

    require('./../wp-blog-header.php');
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");// removes 404.
?>
<?php $r=$_POST['page_num']; echo $r; $args = array('numberposts' => 5 ,'offset' => $r  ); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts($args);?> 
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="small">


<h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div class="size_me" style="position:relative;left:25%;top:25%">
            <?php  if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(thumbnail); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and this is being called via the script from index.php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var abc=45;

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            $('#more').hide();
            $('#no-more').hide();

            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 20) {
                $('#more').css("top","400");
                $('#more').show();
            }
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

                $('#more').hide();
                $('#no-more').hide();

                var data = {
                    page_num: abc
                };

                abc+=5;
                var actual_count = "102";

                if((page-1)* 12 > actual_count){
                    $('#no-more').css("top","400");
                    $('#no-more').show();
                }else{
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "infi.php",
                        data:data,
                        success: function(res) {
                            $(".latest").append(res);
                            console.log(res);
                        }
                    });
                }

            }


        });

    </script>
```

now i removed the 404 error with the line commented as such.
If i remove all wordpress functions required. The variables get passed. but i do need to use these functions for the posts.

Also if i go to end of the page(where the ajax call actually happens) and see my console from google dev tools. it shows me this.

```
POST http://wishpicker.com/blog/infi.php 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.10.2.js:8706




// Do send the request
                    // This may raise an exception which is actually
                    // handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)//line 8706
                    xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

Any help?

Comment: Look in your webserver error logs to find the cause of the error 500.

Comment: i dont see any error logs on my apache2 server.
i mean nothing related to these files. all i get is the error on the console in web dev tools.

i ran vi /var/log/apache2/<name of error log file>

Comment: Open up a terminal, type `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` (or whatever your error log is for that particular virtual host).  Once you are monitoring the log file, **then** trigger the error.  If you don't see anything pop up in the log, you're probably looking at the wrong log file.

Comment: thanks. i got the problem accessing the access logs. the error logs were empty. i'll work on it now. :)

Comment: [Mon Mar 31 08:31:20 2014] [warn] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  require(./../wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/infi.php on line 4, referer: http://<name>.com/blog/

Comment: It appears that solves the problem.  The file you're trying to `require()` isn't where you think it is.  You have the relative path wrong.  Either use an absolute path while requiring the file or make sure the relative path is correct.